# Detecting an unconnected USB-COM port C# .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a piece of software an I need to detect if a USB->UART has nothing connected to it. Currently I'm doing this:

```
    SerialPort coms;

    try
    {
      coms = new SerialPort(comPort);
      //A bunch of stuff about BaudRates etc...
      coms.Open();
    } 
    catch(/*Lots of different exceptions*/)
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Or even if I am doing it correctly.